# ADC values too large on HAL stm32

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor, stm32, hal-library

Hi I am trying to read in a voltage value from a TDS sensor on my stm32 nucleo144-h723zg. The problem is that the voltage values are too high. The manufacturer only provides code and datasheet for arduino programming which I have tried out. The sensor works on arduino but when I translate the same code and formulas over to stmcubeIDE the voltage values are unusable. What I've attached is the forever while loop and the adc initialization from stm32cubemx. *Did I miss something in the initialization or is there something I am overlooking with my sensor?* I'm pretty new to stm32 and HAL library so any help will be appreciated. Thank you

````
while (1)
  {
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      raw = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      voltage = raw * (float)VREF/ 1024.0;
      float compensationCoefficient=1.0+0.02*(temperature-25.0); //temperature compensation formula: fFinalResult(25^C) = fFinalResult(current)/(1.0+0.02*(fTP-25.0));
      float compensationVolatge=voltage/compensationCoefficient; //temperature compensation
      tdsValue=(133.42*compensationVolatge*compensationVolatge*compensationVolatge - 255.86*compensationVolatge*compensationVolatge + 857.39*compensationVolatge)*0.5; //convert voltage value to tds value

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      sprintf(msg, "%0.2f\r\n", tdsValue);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode = {0};
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_16B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ConversionDataManagement = ADC_CONVERSIONDATA_DR;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.LeftBitShift = ADC_LEFTBITSHIFT_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the ADC multi-mode
  */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_15;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  sConfig.OffsetSignedSaturation = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}
```
````

Comment: Most likely differences in the VREF and ADC bit depth, but hard to say because you don't say which specific Arduino the code is for. Usually the generic Mega328 based Arduino is used with a 5V VREF and has a 10-bit ADC which explains the value of 1024 in the code. You must have at most 3.3V VREF and you configure the ADC for 16-bit mode so the values are up to 65535, or 64 times larger than 1024. If that's the problem, I'll make this a formal answer.

Comment: Yep, simply change `1024.0` to `65536.0` to account for resolution change, and set VREF to the appropriate reference voltage value.

Comment: Ahh that seemed to fix it. I also found this out by connecting a potentiometer to my board and finding the max adc value. Thank you!